# CREATING FUNCTIONS mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

im using

```
CREATE FUNCTION UPDATEGames(usernameIN CHAR(15) ,opponientIN CHAR(15) ,mFilePath TINYTEXT,oFilePath TINYTEXT)
BEGIN
UPDATE games  
IF (username = opponientIN AND FilePath = oFilePath) THEN SET opLastTurn = NOW(),Turn=Turn+1 
ELSEIF (username = usernameIN AND FilePath = mFilePath) THEN SET myLastTurn = NOW(),Turn=Turn+1 
END IF 
END;
```

but it didnt worked, what am i ding wrong?and if it isnt possible to do it so then how can i simulate this logic?

Comment: The body of a stored function must be a sequence of valid SQL statements. What you have here … isn't that. How familiar are you with SQL? It's not clear what you're trying to do here, nor that a stored function is an appropriate way to accomplish it.

Comment: what im trying to do is about the logic of my game (not important if you dont understand the logic ) and the SQL statements are Correct (i have tested each part of it without if else and function )

Comment: Well, by introducing the if your sql statement is no longer valid. Within the update you can only use the if **function**, not the if **statement**. And we do need to understand the logic because otherwise we cannot suggest a correct solution.

Comment: You ask "how can i simulate this logic" and then state that it's "not important if you dont understand the logic"? It's your job to *tell* us what are trying to do, that's what duskwuff meant. But if I had to guess, you might want to try `UPDATE games set opLastTurn = NOW(),Turn=Turn+1 where username = opponientIN AND FilePath = oFilePath` (and a 2nd update for `usernameIN`), without the if-thingy. Have an index on username, filepath. Also, a function needs to return something, so maybe use a procedure.

Comment: @ Solarflare , he said It's not clear what you're trying to do here ,i told so about my conditions logic not how to simulate this query cause if want to change it i still wont change the conditions

Comment: @Shadow then if i move the update inside the if ,it would be correct?

Comment: His question was not about your logic. His question was about *what* you want to do. Valid answers to that could be: "I want to update rows in my table for both players that are given as a parameter", or "I already know how to update rows in my table using 2 updates, but I really want to do it in one query, and also I am trying to learn about the "if()"-syntax" or "I have tested each part of it, the code is the following: <insert the code you successfully tested>. Now I want to do exactly this in a procedure."

Comment: @AmirRasti it is a lot less complicated if you used 2 updates. See my answer below.

Comment: i agee dear Solarflare  and sorry about my comment

Comment: @Shadow yes it is a lot less complicated but is it efficient as with conditions? and im trying to learn more about conditions and therefor im more interested on an answer thatway

Comment: In this particular case conditions would make the query less efficient because mysql would have to interpret the conditions on top of everything else. Conditions are really useful if you cannot implement your logic without them. And still you would have to use if function, not if statement. If statement is useful if you want to execute one or the other statement. Actually, here you want to execute both statements, just want them to change different fields.

Comment: yes but two wheres means two time iteration  and i was up to make it one ,and about the if statment you said is it possible to use 'case when' instead?

Answer (score 1):

Within the update you can only use the if **function**, not the if **statement**. The if statement can only be used to execute different sql statements. Furthermore, the `where` criteria must be used in the `update` to restrict the records to be updated.

So, there is no need to use if statement at all, just use two updates. There is no return value either, so I also changed function to procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATEGames(usernameIN CHAR(15) ,opponientIN CHAR(15) ,mFilePath TINYTEXT,oFilePath TINYTEXT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE games SET opLastTurn = NOW(),Turn=Turn+1 WHERE username = opponientIN AND FilePath = oFilePath;
    UPDATE games SET myLastTurn = NOW(),Turn=Turn+1 WHERE username = usernameIN AND FilePath = mFilePath;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: yes but two wheres means two time search iteration and i was up to make it one ,and about the if statment you said is it possible to use 'case when' instead?

Comment: Case statement will also execute one or the other updates, not both. Again, there is a case xpression than you can use instead. As I explained in my previous comment, this particular issue is not a good example for practicing conditional statements. If username and filepath fields are indexed, then these queries will be really fast.